# how initialize char* const argv [] in c++

Tags: c++, c

An API function takes an argument of type 'char *const argv[]'
I am initializing this type of arguments in my c++ application like:

```
char* const  argv[] = {"--timeout=0", NULL};
```

and passing the arguments to API function like:

```
Spawner spawner;
spawner.execute (argv, true);
```

using g++ compiler, I am getting following Error:

```
error: deprecated conversion from string constant to 'char*' [-Werror=write-strings]
```

how can I get rid of above error?

Below is the declaration of execute function in API:

```
void Spawner::execute (char *const argv[], bool bShowChildWindow)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yeah, C++ is annoyingly (but correctly) strict about const chars. Try this

```
char timeoutString[] = "--timeout=0";    // make a non-const char array
char *argv[] = { timeoutString, NULL };
Spawner spawner;
spawner.execute( argv, true );
```

Technically, the problem is with the declaration of the `execute` method, which should be

```
void Spawner::execute (const char *const argv[], bool bShowChildWindow)
```

assuming `execute` doesn't modify the strings or the array.

Answer (score 4):

Aside from disabling `-Werror` for the underlying warning, or disabling the warning altogether, you could do this:

```
char arg0[] = "--timeout=0";
char* const  argv[] = {arg0, NULL};
```

In that case, the string serves as an array initializer; no pointer to it is ever involved.

Answer (score 0):

```
char* const  argv[] = {"--timeout=0", NULL};
```

declares `argv` to be a array of `const` pointers to `char`. It is not a pointer to `const` char.

You can see the error in a simpler statement:

```
char* s = "foo";
```

That can be fixed by using one of the following:

```
char const* s = "foo";  // Points to the read-only memory
char* s[] = "foo";      // Makes a copy of the read-only memory
```

What you need for `argv` is one of the following:

```
char argv1[][50] = {"--timeout=0"}; 
char* argv[] = {argv1[0], NULL};
```

or

```
char argv1[] = "--timeout=0"; 
char* argv[] = {argv1, NULL};
```

and pass `argv` to `Spawner::execute`.

If you don't want the compiler to produce an error with these, you can use `-Wno-write-strings`. But then, if you do that, you will be treading on thin ice. You could end up modifying the read only memory by accident and cause undefined behavior.